# Reload primary router-outlet and empty Auxiliary router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am trying to use auxiliary router-outlet with primary-router-outlet.

**app.routing**

```
const routes: Route[] =[
    {path : 'dashboard', component :  DashboardComponent},
    {path : 'list', component :  ListComponent , outlet :'list'},
    {path : 'detail/:id', component :  DetailComponent , outlet : 'detail'},
```

]

**app.component.html**

```
<a routerLink="dashboard" >Dashboard</a>
<a [routerLink]="[{outlets :{ list :['list'], detail : null  }}]" >list</a>
<a [routerLink]="[{outlets :{ detail :['detail',2] , list:null }}]" >detail</a>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name ="list"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="detail" ></router-outlet>
```

*When I click on list anchor tag, It nullify detail router-outlet and on clicking detail link, list router-outlet get empty which was desired behavior and working fine.*

**Now I want to empty both 'list' and 'detail' router-outlet by clicking on dashboard anchor tag but not working**

Comment: [routerLink]="['dashboard', {outlets : { list:null , detail : null }}]"   is not working

Comment: I can not understand this question. Can you explain something more about this question.